# Loading and reusing image sources (blob)

Tags: javascript, java, html, jetty

I have a client-server application in which I need to load pictures from a server. I'm using the fetch method introduced here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data

It works perfectly and I can place my pictures inside an unordered list.

The point is that I need to reuse the source of the images previously loaded to feed a new list with the same images. However, nothing is displayed in the new list, and when checking the console we can see that the src of the new images are "unknown".

Thank you!

Here are my codes

Server (Java with Jetty Server)

```
import javax.servlet.Servlet;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;

public class MyServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Server server = new Server(8001);

        ServletHandler spriteSerialize = new ServletHandler();
        spriteSerialize.addServletWithMapping(MyJSONSender.class, "/json");
        spriteSerialize.addServletWithMapping(MyImages.class, "/imgs");

        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]
                { 
                        "WAR/views/entryPoint.html",
                });
        resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {resource_handler, spriteSerialize});
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            server.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Server (auxiliary class MyJSONSender)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class MyJSONSender extends HttpServlet
{
     @Override
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
                                                            IOException
        {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

            JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
            obj1.put("name", "axeman");
            obj1.put("img", "oryx/axeman1.png");
            JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
            obj2.put("name", "alien1");
            obj2.put("img", "oryx/alien1.png");
            JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject();
            obj3.put("name", "barrel1");
            obj3.put("img", "oryx/barrel1.png");

            array.add(obj1); array.add(obj2); array.add(obj3);

            String toSend = array.toJSONString();

            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println(toSend);
        }
}
```

Server (auxiliary class MyImages)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyImages extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String imageToServe = req.getParameter("picture");
        System.out.println(imageToServe);

        Path path = Paths.get("sprites/" + 
                imageToServe);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        resp.setContentType("image/png");
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        resp.getOutputStream().write(data);
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Images</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>IMAGES</h1>

<ul id="imageList"></ul>

<ul id="horizontalImageList"></ul>

<script src="load.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var spriteSetObj;

function buildTheSpriteSet(spriteSetObj) {

    var ulElement = document.getElementById('imageList');

    for (var i = 0; i < spriteSetObj.length; i++) {
        getObjectData(spriteSetObj[i], ulElement);
    }

    fillHorizontalList(spriteSetObj);
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        spriteSetObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(spriteSetObj);
        buildTheSpriteSet(spriteSetObj);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8001/json", true);
xmlhttp.send();

function getObjectData(spriteSet, upperUl)
{
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = spriteSet['name'];
    upperUl.appendChild(li);

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.id = spriteSet['name'];
    fetchBlob(spriteSet['img'], img);

    upperUl.appendChild(img);
}

function fillHorizontalList(spriteSet)
{
    var ulHorizontalElement = document.getElementById('horizontalImageList');
    for(var i = 0; i < spriteSet.length; i++)
    {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = document.getElementById(spriteSet[i].name).src;
        ulHorizontalElement.append(img);
    }
}

function fetchBlob(imgPath, imgElement) {
    // construct the URL path to the image file from the product.image property
    var urlSrc = null;
    // Use XHR to fetch the image, as a blob
    // Again, if any errors occur we report them in the console.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "picture=" + imgPath;
    request.open('GET', "http://localhost:8001/imgs" + "?" + params, true);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    var objectURL = null;

    request.onload = function() {
        if(request.status === 200) {
            // Convert the blob to an object URL — this is basically an temporary internal  URL
            // that points to an object stored inside the browser
            var blob = request.response;
            objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            // invoke showProduct
            imgElement.src = objectURL;

        } else {
            alert('Network request for "' + product.name + '" image failed with response ' +     request.status + ': ' + request. statusText);
        }
    };

    request.send();
}
```